# set name to widget's attribute in Twig

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony, twig

I have a field (called name), Every time i write in this field, an ajax script (live search sends data from twig to the controller without reloading)  checks if the data already exist or not showing a message. My problem is that i could't set a name for this field, i tried this but it does not work

```
 {{ form_label(form.name) }}
 {{ form_widget(form.name,{'id':'name','attr':{'name':'name'}}) }}
 {{ form_errors(form.name) }}
```

and here my function in the controller which i'm sure it works properly,

```
    public function searchBackTeamAction(Request $request)
{

    if($request->isXmlHttpRequest())
    {
        $serializer = new Serializer(array(new ObjectNormalizer()));
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $teams= $em->getRepository('TeamBundle:Team')->findOneBy(['name'=>$request->get('name') ]);

        $data = $serializer->normalize($teams);
        return new JsonResponse($data);
    }
}
```

and here is my script i'm also sure that it works properly

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#name").keyup(
                function(){
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "{{ path('team_searchBack') }}",
                        data: $("#name").serialize(),
                        type:"POST",
                        success: function (data, status, object) {
                            console.log(data);
                            if(data.name != null)
                            {
                                $("#error_login").css('display','block');
                                $("#submit").prop('disabled', true);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $("#error_login").css('display','none');
                                $("#submit").prop('disabled', false);
                            }
                        },
                        error: function(req, textStatus, errorThrown,data) {
                            //this is going to happen when you send something different from a 200 OK HTTP

                            console.log('Ooops, something happened: ' + textStatus + ' ' +errorThrown);
                        },
                        complete: function() {
                            // Runs at the end (after success or error) and always runs
                        }
                    });
                })

        }
    );
</script>
```

Could you please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Use following javascript

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#name").keyup(
            function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: "{{ path('team_searchBack') }}",
                    data: {"name": $("#name").val()},
                    type:"POST",
                    success: function (data, status, object) {
                        console.log(data);
                        if(data.name != null)
                        {
                            $("#error_login").css('display','block');
                            $("#submit").prop('disabled', true);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $("#error_login").css('display','none');
                            $("#submit").prop('disabled', false);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(req, textStatus, errorThrown,data) {
                        //this is going to happen when you send something different from a 200 OK HTTP

                        console.log('Ooops, something happened: ' + textStatus + ' ' +errorThrown);
                    },
                    complete: function() {
                        // Runs at the end (after success or error) and always runs
                    }
                });
            })

    }
);
```

Comment: It worked thank you so much for your brilliant idea you really helped me.Just a little note: `data: {"name": $("#name").val()}`and not `data: {"name", $("#name").val()}`.

Comment: Please Accept ans.